# Custom Jackson JsonDeserializer with Artificial Structure

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some code where I would like to artificially nest the serialized value inside a "value" field, and transparently handle that in the deserializer.  Specifically, I have a serialized instance of `getClass()` as VALUE in the JSON structure as: {'value': VALUE} instead of simple VALUE.

Is there a way I could modify the following code to deserialize {'value': VALUE} as if it were just VALUE?

```
  JsonDeserializer dser = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(
      checkNotNull(innerType,
          "Invalid %s: innerType is null. Serialization error?", getClass()));
  Object o = dser.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
  return o;
```